# asp.net not running on Apache 2 on OSX Lion - Getting a Forbidden 403 response

Tags: macos, mono, apache2, http-status-code-403, mod-mono

As of the current time of writing (2012-03-05) I'm running the following components:

- OSX Lion
- Default Apache installation (Apache2)
- SSLEngine on Apache is "on" (doing some dev, but not trying to access .net through ssl yet)
- Mono 2.10.8
- xsp 2.10.2
- mod_mono 2.10

I'm an Win/IIS guy so this is all new to me, but trying to get the xsp test ASP.NET app running on my mac (the app is in the xsp folder and is referenced in the mod_mono install guide).

I've run through the INSTALL guide for xsp and mod_mono.

As far as I can tell everything is running. Appache seems to have loaded the mono module, as it's ok with the mono configuration elements in it's httpd.cong file.

However, when I try to browse to an ASP.NET page, for example, the xsp test one (`http://127.0.0.1/demo/index.aspx`), I get:

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access /demo/index.aspx on this server.
>
> Apache/2.2.20 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.20 OpenSSL/0.9.8r DAV/2 mod_mono/2.10 Server at 127.0.0.1 Port 80

The mono_mod troubleshooting guides say this might happen if Apache doesn't have read acess, but read access on the xsp test folder is set to:

> everyone: Read & Write

I'm thinking it's not a directory permissions issue?

I wonder if the mono mod isn't running properly so actually Apache is trying to do a directory listing, which would give a 403?

What could be causing this? And is there any way to diagnose if all the mono mod stuff is installed and running correctly with Apache?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

A script might also require execute permission, try from the command line:

```
chmod +x /path/to/script.aspx
```

This let's OS X (and other unixes) know that the file can be run.